# BSOD when booting up (nvlddmkm.sys)

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, bsod

### My system

i5-4590, Gigabyte GA-H81M-H, Gigabyte GTX 1060 3GB, Crucial 240GB SSD, running the latest version of Windows 10 Pro. My primary monitor is connected to the graphics card, my secondary monitor to my motherboard (iGPU).

### When does it happen?

It happens when booting up. It does not always happen, I'd say around one in four times.

### What happens?

1) The windows logo will show up on my primary monitor for a second or two (SSD :D)

2) Both of my screens will go black

3) The BSOD will show up on my secondary monitor (powered by integrated graphics), looking stretched out. My secondary monitor is 4:3, the BSOD looks like it was stretched from 16:9.

4) My system will reboot and work just fine.

### Error details?

I managed to take this picture with my phone:
[image: bsod image]

### I have already tried:

- Updating BIOS
- Updating graphics card drivers
- Switching PSU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get [this bugcheck](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557263%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) an the causing driver is `nvlddmkm.sys` which is the nVIDIA GPU driver for your Geforce GTX 1060. Go to [nvidia.com and get the latest driver](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx?lang=en-us) for your card.

As today (2016-12-28), the [driver 376.33](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/113448/en-us) is the latest version. So try this driver.

Comment: Even after updating the drives I still have the same issue. It got worse: when I hibernate my computer it will boot back up automatically after a few seconds. When it boots my computer back up automatically the BSOD  does not happen. Then when I flick the switch on my power supply (when the PC is off) to prevent it from going back on, once I boot my PC back up the BSOD appears. This time it took ~2 minutes to recover (previously ~10 seconds)

Comment: which PSU do you use? maybe it is too weak to support the new GPU

Comment: An EVGA 430W. I have not overclocked the GPU (I sometimes even underclock it during the summer)

Comment: By the way, the automatic rebooting issue is apparently an issue with my mouse/keyboard (CM MasterKeys Lite L), when I unplug it it does not happen.

Comment: are there any drivers for the mouse/keyboard? also update them or go back to the default input drivers of windows

Comment: I have not installed any drivers, and according to device manager it's a generic USB device.

Comment: how do you control the keyboard features like the backlight color? There must be a software/driver settings somewhere.

Comment: Hardware buttons. By the way, the issue has disappeared after the drivers update, or at least I haven't had it in a while..

Comment: which drivers have you updated?

Comment: Graphics card drivers. By the way, I just had it bluescreen again, so the issue has not been solved unfortunately.

Comment: also update the BIOS/UEFI: http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4737#bios

Comment: When I tried updating the bios (I opened autoexec.bat in the zip) it gave me this error: http://i.imgur.com/wH4fQa2.png ("The program or feature [...] incompatibility with 64-bit versions of Windows. Please [...]."). I have tried updating "Intel VGA Driver" too, because my secondary monitor is hooked up via VGA, but it said a newer version was already installed. Interestingly, it said "16 bit application" in the error message. 16-bit!?

Comment: this is a DOS program, you need to create a bootable USB flash drive or floppy and boot from it (DOS)

Comment: I'll just use QFlash, that's way easier :P

Comment: does the new BIOS/UEFi improve stability?

Comment: It doesn't. I have tried switching the power supply to a Corsair CX430M I had laying around, but that didn't work. I have now noticed it happens when booting up normally too (not out of hibernation)

Comment: remove the nvidia GPU and only use the Intel HD from the CPU and look if the PC is now stable.

Comment: It will be, I started having this issue after installing the GPU. I have ran my computer using its integrated GPU for a few months before buying a dedicated GPU.

Comment: can you test the GPU in a 2nd PC or at a friends PC? Maybe the nVIDIA card itself is damaged.

Comment: I think the problem might be the motherboard. That will also explain why my keyboard and mouse don't work well with it. I'll try connecting my boot drive to another machine and put the video card in too. Then reboot like 30 times and see if I get a BSOD.

Comment: After A LOT of testing:

1) Same windows installation, same graphics card, same power supply, different motherboard (and cpu): **No problems** (after 11 reboots and 7 hibernations)
2) Same windows installation, different graphics card, same power supply, same motherboard: **No problems** (after 3 reboots and 8 times hibernated)
3) (just to verify I tested it again) Same everything: **BSOD** (after hibernating 2 times)

Comment: So the motherboard works, the video card works, but together they don't.

Comment: hm, thanks for the testing. so replace the Motherboard/CPU and sell the old one via ebay or use it in a 2nd PC.

Comment: I'm planning to wait for Ryzen then buy a new motherboard/cpu combo. For now I'll have to change my habit of hibernating instead of shutting down. Thanks for the help! I'll choose this answer as the accepted answer.